# Find the value of a for the intersection between these functions

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions

$2.55<a<2.85$, where $e^x$ intersects exactly once with $x^a$ whilst $x>0$.
Find the value for $a$, at which this single intersection occurs. ($a$ must be a 
real number)

I would really appreciate it if somebody could post the solution to this problem, have been struggling to solve for a while.

I have tried solving $e^x = x^a$ by differentiation however i feel this is the wrong approach as i always end up with $x = a$ which sounds completely wrong.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Are you asking us to find $a$ such that $2.55<a<2.85$ and $e^x=x^a$ has exactly one solution for $x>0$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE . We will appreciate your insights on this problem. Your research, and at least what you have tried .  asking such questions without your approach will attract less contributors.

Comment: @DeadLegend Sorry about that, have updated my post with more details.

Comment: @user440866 You may be able to convince yourself by looking at some graphs that if $e^x$ and $x^a$ intersect in exactly one point, then they are tangent at that point. So you are correct to set $e^x=x^a$ and set their derivatives equal as well. $x=a$ will be the point of intersection, but you need to fiddle around with a few more equations to get the value of $a$.

Comment: @mrnovice Yep thats right

Comment: @Allan I have tried differentiating it with no results, also tried $a=e$ but that had no intersections. I then desperately took to trying numbers with hundreth increments. Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

You write yourself that after differentiating, you arrive at $x=a$. This does make sense, however: This is the value of $x$ that satisfy the equality, i.e., this is were the slopes of the two functions are equal.

Inserting into the original equation, we have 
$$e^x=x^a\rightarrow e^a=a^a,$$
which can only be satisfied if $a=e,$ which is indeed the answer.